# Why do I see the "/usr/bin/env" command in the history when I didn't use it?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

When using the `history` command, I see "/usr/bin/env" in the history when I didn't use it, how is this possible? How can I fix or troubleshoot it?

There is terminal output after the `history` command.

`1178  2020-04-16 03:14:41 history
 1179  2020-04-16 04:47:42 shutdown -P 6:00
 1180  2020-04-16 15:11:08 /usr/bin/env
 1181  2020-04-16 15:00:51 sudo protonvpn reconnect
 1182  2020-04-17 03:01:07 /usr/bin/env
 1183  2020-04-17 04:58:04 history
 1184  2020-04-17 04:58:39 shutdown -P 6:00
 1185  2020-04-17 15:08:14 history
 1187  2020-04-17 15:45:54 iptables -h
 1190  2020-04-17 15:47:57 history
 1191  2020-04-18 00:07:28 sudo protonvpn reconnect
 1192  2020-04-18 02:08:08 sudo protonvpn disconnect
 1193  2020-04-18 **07:40:20** /usr/bin/env
 1194  2020-04-18 **07:28:04** sudo protonvpn reconnect
 1195  2020-04-18 18:10:38 history
 1196  2020-04-18 18:12:46 sudo protonvpn reconnect
 1197  2020-04-18 18:18:22 sudo protonvpn disconnect
 1198  2020-04-18 22:01:47 history`

A new thing that I am recognized is that line of `1193` executed after line `1194` but listed before it(line of `1180` and `1181` are in the same condition).

Comment: You can start by updating our question with the exact thing you see .. then we might be able to see what the problem is. Do you see a text message or what ?

Comment: This is a strange list. First, it includes `shutdown -P` which no ordinary user should be able to do without using `sudo`. Then, later that day, a `sudo` command is given, without any arguments, after one of these `/usr/bin/env` commands but with an earlier time stamp?

Comment: FYI, please don't provide terminal output as images. It is difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification. Instead, copy and paste the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, I edited it.